# Displaying a zero

Tags: php, output, zero

I'm filling a template with some values being numbers, using str_replace.
When a number is 0 (zero), PHP thinks it's false and write nothing.

I tried every solution found on SO and the web :

- intval($myZeroVar)
- floatval($myZeroVar)
- strval($myZeroVar)
- (string)$myZeroVar
- ''.$myZeroVar
- random tests using number_format, sprintf, str_pad...

NONE of these are working.

The only way to display it is to concatenate $myZeroVar with a space (`$myZeroVar.' '`).
But what if I don't want this space ??

Am I doing something wrong ? In PHP config maybe ?

Don't tell me you are all concatenating a space everytime you're outputting a number ?

Thanks

EDIT :

Here is my awesome templating system (just kidding) :

```
$template = 'Some text with a {value}';
$data = 0;
$template = str_replace('{value}', $data, $template);
```

Result is : "Some text with a "

**Edit : SOLVED**

Ok. Just before I run to hide under my desk, I must tell you that the problem came from a line just before my awesome templating system :

```
if(!empty($data)
```

So now I replaced this by `$val === '' || $val === null`

And everything is fine...
I love losing hours to solve problems caused by me.

Look like I will never make a useful post here !

Thanks everybody.

Don't downvote too much, this post is somewhat useful for newcomers : 
ALWAYS CHECK 3 TIMES !

Comment: Doesn't every language think 0 = false? Can you add more code and what you are getting and what you are expecting, no clue what you are trying to do..

Comment: *"Sometimes I hate this stupid language."* - that's a craftsman blaming it on his tools. It's not the "tool's fault". I removed that rant from your question.

Comment: @naruto: He wants to declare 0 as a string, not as an int which is false's representation. On my easyPHP dev server, (string)$myZeroVar is working, var_dump('0') also. I think it comes from your configuration.

Comment: It could also be the template system you are using which does a lazy comparison before outputting the value, and since a lazy comparison will evaluate `null, 0, '', false` all as false that's likely what is happening.

Comment: var_dump('0'); is outputting zero as a string. @Augwa : my templating system is just str_replace in a loop, nothing more.

Comment: post your code, so we can see what is happening sometimes it's a silly thing that a 2nd set of eyes can pick out.

Comment: the sample code provided works fine ... https://eval.in/319441

Comment: @FC = If you actually run the code as you've posted, you'll see that PHP isn't doing what yu claim, but is correctly displaying the 0 - [Demo](http://3v4l.org/RbogT)

Comment: @Naruto - no, shell scripts think that an exit value >0 indicates a failure or false.  Check the exit value of /bin/true and /bin/false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My variable was not displayed, not because of some bugs or bad configuration, but because the template is filled only if the variable is not `empty()`.

And the empty function returns `true` for 0.

Replacing `!empty($var)` with `($var !== '' && $var !== null)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<?php
    echo "{$myZeroVar}";
?>
```

its worked for me "{$var}" that format has stopped php reading it as true/false and as a string instead

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Nice try, but same result :)

Answer (score 0):

How about running a test to see if the value is zero. Then modify it to be a string zero instead?

```
$template = 'Some text with a {value}';
$data = 0;
if (!$data) {
  $data = "0";
}
$template = str_replace('{value}', $data, $template);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.sprintf.php) instead of str_replace?

This way you can set your data type in your string template.

```
$template = 'Some text with a %d';
$data = 0;
$result = sprintf($template, $data);
```

Comment: sprintf was one of my test :) I was just testing the wrong place... :D

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` command and its friends handle formatting like what you want.

```
$template = "Some text with a %.0f\n";
$data = 0;
$output = sprintf($template, $data);
```

If you want to convert your template to printf format from within your software, that's an option too.

```
$template = "Some text with a {value}\n";
$data = 0;
$template_fmt = str_replace('{value}', '%.0f', $template);
$output = sprintf($template_fmt, $data);
```

Note that I'm using `%.0f` instead of `%d` because it offers you an easy progression towards support of more complex floating point numbers.  Either should do.

Comment: Thanks my friend but please don't waste more time. Problem caused by empty()... I don't know what I should do with threads like this ?

Comment: @FC' .. Glad you solved it! If your solution was hinted at in an answer, select that answer with a checkmark.  If it wasn't, and your question missed the mark somehow, clarify in your question, and post your own answer and select it.  Nobody will get "best anser" points for it, but it will clearly identify what the problem and solution were, which is more important.